# Java/JSP output a text file

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsp

I need to make a "text" file available on my site so that a partner can read the data daily. I'd like this "text" file to be generated dynamically.  We use JSPs and Java Servlets for of our pages

Is there a way to dynamically generate a text file dynamically to be downloaded when the user visits my JSP or a Java Servlet url?

I have tried using a JSP without any html in it. It does put some text on the page, but I can't seem to include line breaks in the output so I think it may be better to just serve it as a file to be downloaded.

Comment: Can you elaborate this issue? `but I can't seem to create new lines in the output.`

Comment: Can you post some code with how you're writing to the output now. Do you want to present the user with a txt file to download or just display some text in a webpage?

Answer (score 2):

To generate some text and download it, you can use something like this:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet( name = "TextOutputServlet", urlPatterns = { "/servlets/giveMeSomeText" } )
public class TextOutputServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void processRequest( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response )
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType( "text/plain;charset=UTF-8" );
        response.setHeader( "Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=MyTextFile.txt" );
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        try {

            out.println( "Some content..." );
            out.println( "Some more..." );

        } finally {            
            out.close();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response )
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest( request, response );
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response )
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest( request, response );
    }

}
```